# Magento 2 error in inline css apply in email template

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, magento-2.1

i have issue regarding apply in line css in email template.

it's showing following error in my email template

```
CSS inlining error: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /var/www/magento2/public_html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 269
```

i also update pelago reference [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4737) but no luck.

Comment: Have same issue ! Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I got solution perfect solution, you need to update 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/201343/edit

/var/www/html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php 
Line 595,

```
 $search = array(
            // get rid of css comment code
            '/\\/\\*.*\\*\\//sU',
            // strip out any import directives
            '/^\\s*@import\\s[^;]+;/misU',
            // strip remains media enclosures
            '/^\\s*@media\\s[^{]+{(.*)}\\s*}\\s/misU',
            '/^\\s*@-?[A-Za-z-]+\\s[^{]+{(.*)}\\s*}\\s/misU',
        );

        $replace = array(
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution for Magento 2

**created the files**

> /web/css/email.less

and

> /web/css/email-inline.less

in my custom theme and added the content from

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less

and

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.css
>   respectively

**Please Note below**

**but each with the line "@import 'source/_theme.less';" commented out (or removed)**

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
My PHP version: 7.2.32
composer require pelago/emogrifier:2.0.0
```

It was not working with pelago/emogrifier:2.2.0

Thanks,